# Laravel 5.1 - get month and day of date (with different variables)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

i have my article resource controller, like this:

```
public function articles()
{
    $articles = Article::OrderBy('id','DESC')->paginate(3);
    return view('blog', compact('articles'));
}
```

I would like to pass two variables to my view, like this:

```
$day = day of created article 
$month = month of created article 
return view('blog', compact('articles','day','month'));
```

But I don't know how to get this data from the database, I can get the date of creation like this :

```
$article->created_at
```

How can I get only the day and the month to pass to my view?

Comment: By "mount", do you mean "month"?

Comment: sorry i crrected! i mean month!

Comment: are you fetching all of the articles then you want an array of their days and months or are you fetching just one?

Answer (score 5):

By default, `created_at` is cast to a Carbon instance ([reference](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators)). Because of that, you can get the day and month attributes directly from the property!

```
@foreach($articles as $article)
    {{ $article->created_at->day }}
    {{ $article->created_at->month }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Or use $article->created_at->format('d M'); depending on how you want to format the date - Also if created_at is null, it will return error

Comment: True, @Daelune; you have access to all of Carbon's methods. While it's highly unlikely that the `created_at` field would be null (it gets set to the current timestamp when inserting the record), it's possible that the original database schema doesn't have a default value. In that case, you'd have to guard against null (as you would have to do anyways) with something like `$article->created_at === null ? '' : $article->created_at->format('d M')`

Answer (score 1):

The `created_at` attribute should be  a datetime in Laravel.

To get the day and month from it, you can do this :

```
$day = date('d', strtotime($article->created_at));
$month = date('m', strtotime($article->created_at));
```